# MySQL duplicating Insert Queries while backup is running

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, dump

I have a Windows Task Job Running every night at 3 am that is backing up all the databases via a batch file, it backs up everything just fine.

However if someone is inserting a record into the database while the back up is running, it runs into an issue where it duplicates the insert query about 10-30 times.

User Inserts data into the MySQL database by a PHP webpage, once the insert is done PHP redirects the page to a fresh version of the current page so refreshing or hitting back the page will not do anything.

The duplicate entries happen only while the backup is running.

Comment: Are you using mysqldump to do your backup, or code (php)?

Comment: If you don't mind that your backup isn't incremental, why don't you simply copy the actualy database files to your backup location instead of doing it all inside php or mysql itself. It's usually quite a bit faster since it doesn't have to read / parse and execute anything. It simply copies. Alternatively, you could also lock your tables while backing up. Put up a signal somewhere, have it set to true while backing up, and in that time, tell users the servers are offline for a few moments.

Comment: @Tularis Copying the database files is a **super bad idea** unless they're in a consistent state. The safe way to do this is to use a tool like [innobackupex](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/innobackupex_script.html) or the [hot backup feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.5/en/meb-backup-overview.html).

Comment: Assuming a consistent state, of course. The alternative of incremental backups would be preferred; but I don't think the OP understands enough of MySQL to know how to do that properly

Comment: I am using mysqldump

I shall take your advise and lock the tables or back up the data files directly.

Comment: @Tularis Having a copy of the files may lead to a false sense of security, they're probably corrupted and missing tons of data since it'll have to replay the journal to repair the damage.

Comment: A backup is by definition outdated. And your database should be in a consistent state. Making a copy of the database can even be performed within MySQL itself by issuing a COPY DATABASE command which would remedy that

Comment: @Tularis: Innodb tables simply cannot be recovered from their data files.  DO NOT BACKUP YOUR DATABASE IN THIS FASHION.

Comment: I KNOW innoDB tables are different. However most people (most likely including the OP) are still using MyISAM tables which CAN be backed up this way. Let's just end this discussion with a simple "use mysqldump instead", shall we... (edit: apparently the OP was using innoDB, so in this case, yes, you're right. My advice was incorrect)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using `mysqldump` be sure that you're using the transaction snapshot feature by enabling `--single-transaction`.

There's a lot of options that control how the dump is captured and what options to include.

My defaults:

```
mysqldump --create-options --extended-insert --add-drop-table --single-transaction --hex-blob
```

Comment: It's really hard to read stuff like that in a comment, better to amend your question with the additonal data.

Comment: Try the `--single-transaction` option. You are using InnoDB for all tables, right? `SHOW TABLE STATUS` will tell you.

Comment: yes the are all innoDB. I am going to try the --single-transaction I will let you know if it is successful.

Comment: adding --single-transaction worked. Thank for you help, I can't vote it up because I don't have a rep of 15 yet.